# Project jmeter portable after to have build with maven

Tags: maven, jmeter, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin, mvn-repo

I'm building a project jmeter with maven. In general I pass some argument in input.

Typically I build and run with an example command as the following:

mvn clean verify "-DNrOperators=3" -DProject.jmx=Myproject.jmx -Dtarget=Test

It produces some folders in target : logs, results, testFiles and I see the results in those folders.

Now I would like to make the project portable. That is, once the project has been built by maven on an host A , I would execute the project on another host B, without any rebuild activity, but only executing the built project

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The steps you need to do are:

1. Make sure that [Java is installed](https://openjdk.org/install/) on the host B
2. Make sure that [Maven is installed](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) on the host B (unless you're using the [Maven Wrapper](https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/))
3. Copy the [local repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html#artifact-repositories) folder from the host A to the host B, normally it's `.m2` folder in your user home folder
4. Copy your project from host A to host B
5. Run `mvn clean verify`

More information: [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. related to the point 1."Make sure that Java is installed on the host B".  Is there a way to include by maven ( and with pom.xml configuration) also Java in the project ? so I could avoid to install separately Java. 

Thanks

Comment: Another question:

Related to the point  "3. Copy the local repository folder from the host A to the host B, normally it's .m2 folder in your user home folder." .
How should be referred the .m2 folder from Host B ? 
Thanks